# FileNotFoundError exception thrown while trying to connect to DataStax AstraDB with Cassandra-driver and python

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra, fastapi, datastax-astra

While trying to connect to DataStax AstraDB using the secure_connect_bundle.zip, FileNotFoundError has been thrown. The error seems to generate from the driver as it tries to read from a tempfile it has created by unzipping the .zip file.

This is the code while needs to be run

```
cloud_config = {
        'secure_connect_bundle': 'secure-connect-bundle.zip',
                'use_default_tempdir': True,
           }
  
username, password = os.environ.get('CASSANDRA_USERNAME', None), os.environ.get('CASSANDRA_PASSWORD', None)
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=username, password=password)
  
cluster = Cluster(cloud=cloud_config, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()
```

The error image is given below
[Error Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLwjm.png)

Comment: Just curious, but what happens when you remove the `use_default_tempdir` config line?  I've never seen anyone use that before.